# how to get origin of an stl file , from ascii stl file

Tags: python, stl, numpy

I have a stl file, content as usual

```
 solid b'STLB ATF 10.10.0.1391 COLOR=\xa0\xa0\xa0\xff'
 facet normal 0.741056 0.036405 0.000000
   outer loop
     vertex -4.739567 6.865542 1.587500
     vertex -4.739567 6.865542 0.000000
     vertex -4.762500 7.332349 1.587500
   endloop
 endfacet
```

I have to modify the file using code, can I choose any point like 1,1,1 as the origin.

the end goal is to finally get a plane based on points associated with a particular normal. for planar information, I need to place origin somewhere as I will be modifying planes on one axis to scan through all points/triangles/surfaces.

let's say I am moving on the z-axis with delta = 0.001 units.

any more information regarding scale-related information any knowledge around stl file read and write programmatically would be great.

Comment: Please see if the information here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120837/programmatically-altering-stl-cad-files-with-python> is helpful for you.

Comment: Hello, could you rephrase your question so it is related to Blender ?